# Asynchronous job scheduling in windows and Linux

Tags: php, asynchronous, cron

I a have an application that is written in PHP and runs on Linux using  LAMP stack and in Windows using XMPP stack (The PHP functions are called from Apache). I have requirements to kick off some activity periodically from the server side.

Currently I have the user use  cron in Linux and and task scheduler in windows to kick off a PHP script which in turn calls the webserver to start the activity.

Both (Linux Cron and Windows Task scheduler) these options are cumbersome during deployment (Even with a detailed instructions it ends up incorrectly setup). So I am looking for a platform agnostic way to schedule async jobs.

Looking around, I see things like Celery (which seems more suited for Python). Are there any other facilities that can be used to achieve this function?

Comment: If you vote to close, at least add comment as to the reason. If it is generic, then more details can be added. Otherwise every single question that will survive will be just syntax questions.

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish instead of just saying you're using cron or windows task scheduler to schedule some task. What is the task you are scheduling?

Comment: There are periodic task (Primarily Report generations, and alerts gathering and notifications) that needs to be run at various intervals . Typically we have it running hourly (and we use multipliers to schedule the tasks).

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what is your deployment model? I have worked with many deployments, where the post deployment sets the cron job in Linux properly. I am not familiar with Windows deployment, but that wont be difficult if you have proper deployment model and scripts to do this. There are many ways to do 99% reliable post installations and do more than cron job setup. But without knowing your deployment model i could not suggest you proper options.